Has the sponsored tags feature been sunsetted or totally superseded by Collectives?
I just ran this userscript (updated with the current total pages of tags and waited for it to finish scraping all the thousands of pages), and nothing was printed in my browser console. I then did some research and found out the last sponsored tags that I could determine have their sponsorship ended on December 3, 2023, and the sponsor-tag-img CSS class annotating the image icons of the sponsored tags has been removed from primary.css since the May 21 update. I could not find any announcement of the beginning or ending of the sponsored tags feature (first usage seen with Adobe on September 30, 2009?).
Has the sponsored tags feature been incorporated into Collectives?

The CSS class still exists, it was just renamed to s-tag--sponsor for consistency. Our design is publicly documented: https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/tags/

@animuson that looks like an answer to me, you might want to post it as one.
